# Access SharePoint Online files from daemon app

Tags: office365, sharepoint-online, microsoft-graph-api

Is it possible for a daemon app (app only, no authenticated user) to access SharePoint Online content via the Microsoft Graph API? If not, what are my options?

I tried:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/<id>
```

But got access denied.

Accessing drive in Office 365 Groups works via:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/<id>/drive
```

This is how I retrieve the authorization token:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant id>/oauth2/token
resource=https://graph.microsoft.com
grant_type=client_credentials
client_id=<client id>
client_secret=<client secret>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that you can read the group files is that the app-only token has the **Group.Read.All** rule. There is no such app-only scope like **Files.Read.All** to permits the app read all the files on the SharePoint online site.

At present, the Microsoft Graph API only support to get the files belongs himself/herself or the files others share to himself/herself using the delegate token.

If you want the app get the files doesn't user login-in, a possible workaround is that you can get the access token and refresh token manually at the first time and save them in the app. Then you can call the REST API with access token, and renew the access token/refresh token when it is expired.

You may submit the feedback from [here](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/) if you require this feature.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Are you saying that the daemon app could run for months using the refresh token? It will be scheduled to run once a day.

Comment: Yes. The refresh tokens are valid for 14 days, and with continuous use, they can be valid up to 90 days. After 90 days, users will be asked to re-authenticate. Refer detail [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Session-timeouts-for-Office-365-37a5c116-5b07-4f70-8333-5b86fd2c3c40?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US).

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked [Build service and daemon apps in Office 365](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/howto/building-service-apps-in-office-365). The basic idea is to create a Azure AD App to use App-only token. The following is a summary of steps:

- Create your Azure AD App
- Create a certificate to secure your token request process. You need
  to update certificate information in Azure AD App manifest file.
- Configure Azure AD App's configuration to allow certain permission
  under "Application Permissions" list.

By using App-only token, your application can behalf of other uses inside your Azure AD. You can call `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/{user's UPN or ID}/drive/root/children` to get that user's files based on Graph API. I have tried this approach to access the content inside the SharePoint lists and doc libraries. When I updated the list item or documents, the "Modified By" was shown to that Azure AD App's name.
I also used the same approach to access outlook to send email on behalf of an service account. For detail, please reference to [Send email on behalf of a service account using Office Graph API](https://medium.com/@frankchen2016/send-email-on-behalf-of-a-service-account-using-office-graph-api-6b013728a155#.ogm8h7sg2)

I hope it helps and let me know if you have questions for app-only token configurations.

Comment: Thanks. Could you show me an example of REST call to access a SharePoint list? For example how would I access items in a tasks list called ToDoList in the site mytenant.sharepoint.com/SiteName?

Comment: For complete version, please reference to https://github.com/frankchen76/MediumSample/tree/master/AppOnlySPOSample which I just created.

Comment: thanks, but I am afraid this is not what I am looking for. My question is about accessing SP lists via the Graph API, and from what I understand your sample is about accessing e-mail (and without the Graph API).

Comment: My sample originally came from sending email via Graph API. Since the mechanism is same, I used the same way to get access token and access SPO REST API. You can find setting from line 26 to line 32 for SPO. For Graph API, you can only access the file associated with a specific user not a list. Your original question is "Is it possible for a daemon app (app only, no authenticated user) to access SharePoint Online content via the Microsoft Graph API? If not, what are my options?" I think you probably can use SPO REST API to get SPO content via app-only token for a daemon application.